# Can I make a SymmetricKey with my own key value?

Tags: cryptography

Mathematica has a function that one can use like this

```
GenerateSymmetricKey[Method -> <|"Cipher" -> "AES128", "BlockMode" -> "CBC"|>]
```

but it picks the value for Key (16 bytes), and I want to provide that, as it's generated outside of MMA in my case.  Is there a way for me to do this?

I was about to try desperate things like

```
 mykey = GenerateSymmetricKey[...];
 mykey["Key"] = ...;
```

but that seems like an abstraction violation.  Just looking at the interface to this function either makes me think that I'm missing something important, or that they just don't have a very useful design.

Also, when one gets a `SymmetricKey`, how can I look "inside" it?  It is presented as an opaque object, and I'm sure that this is Mathematica 101 (although I couldn't figure it out).

Many thanks!  :)

Comment: You can use `InputForm` (or `FullForm`) to "look inside."

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully I don't misunderstand your question.  We can look at the input form of the [`SymmetricKey`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetricKey.html) using, appropriately, [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html):

```
mykey = GenerateSymmetricKey[Method -> <|"Cipher" -> "AES128", "BlockMode" -> "CBC"|>];

mykey // InputForm
```

> ```
> SymmetricKey[<|"Cipher" -> "AES128", 
>   "BlockMode" -> "CBC", "Key" -> 
>    ByteArray["ZECnBd3OGoeAXK2Dc/KZSA=="], 
>   "InitializationVector" -> None|>]
> ```

If you already have a `"Key"` value to use you could construct this expression directly.  For example using a separately generated random key:

```
SeedRandom[0]
rndKey = RandomInteger[255, 16] // ByteArray;

new =
  SymmetricKey[<|
    "Cipher" -> "AES128", 
    "BlockMode" -> "CBC",
    "Key" -> rndKey, 
    "InitializationVector" -> None
  |>]
```

[image]